# React Redux shallowEqual source code bug or on purpose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When I read the source code of React Redux(5.0.1), I find there is a line I really do not understand.

Here is the source code, and the link to [github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/v5.0.1/src/utils/shallowEqual.js):

```
const hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty

export default function shallowEqual(a, b) {
   if (a === b) return true

   let countA = 0
   let countB = 0

   for (let key in a) {
      if (hasOwn.call(a, key) && a[key] !== b[key]) return false
      countA++
   }

   for (let key in b) {
      if (hasOwn.call(b, key)) countB++
   }

   return countA === countB
}
```

In the first for loop, should the countA only be increased if and only if 'key' is a own property? Otherwise, shallowEqual will always return false if there is a property in the prototype, such as:

```
Object.prototype.bar = "bar"
```

Not sure whether it is a bug or on purpose. 
Please help and explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right. Should be something like this:

```
for (let key in a) {
    if (hasOwn.call(a, key)){
        if(a[key] !== b[key]){
            return false
        }else{
            countA++
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise this will print false:

```
let obj1 = {a:1}

let obj2 = {b:1}
obj2.__proto__ = obj1 

let obj3 = {b:1}
obj3.__proto__ = obj1 

console.log(shallowEqual(obj2 , obj3))
```